# Google maps on iOS - query string to achieve what I need

Tags: google-maps, ios

I would like Google maps to show indoor maps on iOS. I use Google API on Android, but accordingly to their site, Google maps SDK for iOS does not support indoor mapping.

Thus, I think the closest thing I can come is showing URLs like this in embedded browser:

> https://maps.google.com/maps?q= %string% &output=embed'

I would like the query string to achieve the following:

- Multiple markers (I think one is max)
- Enable position location (so user can see himself as arrow/dot)
- Hybrid view

Comment: That is three questions. Can you edit this one and create 2 more, it is how Stack Exchange works.

Comment: Well, all things are set in the same query string (and could theoreticly also affect each other)

Comment: iOS now supports indoor mapping http://appleinsider.com/articles/13/07/16/google-maps-for-ios-adds-ipad-support-live-traffic-updates-and-indoor-navigation

Comment: Looks promising. Upvoted. (However, I am still interested in the original question since I develop iOS apps in Delphi, and I will need some time for how to best use Google Maps for iOS in Delphi. But for longterm, I will probably switch to Google Maps for iOS if their API/SDK supports indoor mapping as well on iOS)

Answer (score 1):

According to this page:
[Maps for mobile > Indoor Maps availability](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/1685827?hl=en) , indoor maps are also available in the mobile version. Since you are launching this from your app, it would be wise to retrieve the user location before opening the embedded browser and then send the location in the URL as a parameter. Also the indoor maps are showed from the 18th zoom level and on.

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660201/what-parameters-should-i-use-in-a-google-maps-url-to-go-to-a-lat-lon) , this should work in any version of google maps, although the new version of google maps for desktop has different parameters names, but it appears that the parameters get translated from the old version.:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?z=12&t=m&q=loc:38.9419+-78.3020&sensor=true
```

- `z` is the zoom level (1-20)
- `t` is the map type ("m" map, "k" satellite,
  "h" hybrid, "p" terrain, "e" GoogleEarth)
- `q` is the search query, if
  it is prefixed by loc: then google assumes it is a lat lon separated
  by a +
- `sensor` tells google if the device is capable to get its location.

Comment: Thanks. I gave bounty + upvote. Will check back later today